# Most efficient way to insert/update records with Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am developing an app that downloads data from a server regularly. If the data needs updated, I use something like to following to update the records or insert new records if they don't exist.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Trip")
    for csvTrip in csvTrips {
        var trip: NSManagedObject!

        let tripId = Int(csvTrip[0])!
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %d", tripId)

        if (context.count(for: fetch) == 0) {
            trip = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Trip", into: context)
            trip.setValue(tripId, forKey: "id")
        } else {
            tripObject = (context.fetch(fetch) as! [NSManagedObject])[0]
        }

        // Set other properties
    }
```

Checking if the entity already exists in each loop makes it about 100 times slower than just inserting them without checking, which becomes a big problem with more than a few thousand entities. I've tried fetching all the entities first, but I still have to loop through each one and add the id to an array or something, which isn't much faster. I know core data isn't the same as MySQL, but it's hard for me to believe that there isn't a feature similar to INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, which is extremely fast in MYSQL. Am I missing something?

Comment: Fetching all of the ids and loading them into a `Set` should be pretty quick

Comment: Is there a way to just get the IDs specifically? The only way I know how is to fetch every object and loop through them each to add them to the set, which was not any faster when I tried.

Comment: You can set the `propertiesToFetch` property of the fetch request to only return `id`. Also set the result type to `dictionaryResultType`.  You can then fetch all of your current objects and quickly load the ids into a set using a `map` operation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would be surprised if fetching even a few thousand entities and loading the ids into a `Set` took a particularly long time.

You could use something like:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Trip")
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["id"]
do {
   if let results = try self.moc.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [[String:Any]] {
       let idSet = Set<Int32>(results.flatMap({ (dict) -> Int32? in
                return dict["id"] as? Int32
        }))
   }
 } catch {
     print("Error reading trips")
 }
```

Now you can easily check if a given id is new or not and insert a new trip if required:

```
for csvTrip in csvTrips {
    if let tripId = Int(csvTrip[0]) {
        if !idSet.contains(tripId) {
            trip = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Trip", into: context)
            trip.setValue(tripId, forKey: "id")
        }
     }
}
```

In my test, this took 1.35 seconds to load 320,000 trips ids into a set and 0.08s to create 10,000 new trips whilst checking to see if the trip id was contained in the set.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Core Data's *unique constraints* technique.

1. Tell Core Data that your *id* is a unique identifier.
   To do this, select your data model (Trip.xcdatamodeld) and make sure the Trip entity is selected rather than one of its attributes.
   In the Data Model inspector see a field "Constraints" and click the + button at the bottom of that field.
   A new row will appear saying "comma,separated,properties". Click on that, hit Enter to make it editable, then type *id* and hit Enter again. Save changes by pressing Cmd+S.

[image]

2. Modify the `loadPersistentStores()` method call to allow Core Data update your objects:

```
container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
    self.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

    if let error = error {
        print("Unresolved error \(error)")
    }
}
```

**Note**:
Using attribute constraints can cause problems with `NSFetchedResultsController`: attribute constraints are only enforced as unique when a save happens, which means if you're inserting data then an `NSFetchedResultsController` may contain duplicates until a save takes place. You can avoid it by performing a save before a load. Just know that it's up to you to make such changes.

You can read more about this technique [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/6/how-to-make-a-core-data-attribute-unique-using-constraints).

Comment: If you want to write an answer about unique constraints then do so but link only answers go stale and change.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I've updated an answer with details keeping the link if someone would be curious about the theory

Comment: This was the easiest way to do what _should_ be an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed up insertion/updation would be by slicing your input array into reasonably small "buckets" and using the `IN` operator in NSPredicate. With the `IN` operator you can check whether *all* elements of the bucket are already present in the db with a **single** query. Let me illustrate that with some code.

```
let bucketSize = 10

let bucketStart = 0
let bucketEnd = bucketSize

while bucketStart < csvTrips.count {
    let tripBucket = csvTrips[bucketStart..<bucketEnd]

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Trip")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id in %@", tripBucket.map {Int($0[0])})

    // count == bucketSize would imply that all elements in the bucket are also in the db, in which case we simply move on to the next bucket
    if context.count(for: fetch) != bucketSize {
        // some of the elements in the bucket are not in the db,
        // now use your existing code to update the missing ones
        for csvTrip in tripBucket {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // update bucketStart and bucketEnd here
}
```

You can tune the efficiency of this algorithm by changing the bucket size. You must pick a size taking into account the probability of new records in your input data so that maximum no. of buckets *do not* enter the following block of code.

```
if context.count(for: fetch) != bucketSize {...}
```

A bucket size too large would mean that almost all buckets will have at least one element missing from the database; which in turn would mean you will get little to no advantage over your existing method. On the other hand, a bucket size too small would mean the overhead of the extra fetch requests (`id in %@`) will be too large.