# Update CoreData when fetch again from online Json

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am fetching data from Json and save all at once in CoreData. I introduced a new entity "isFavorite" to mark core data posts as favorites. The problem is that after i fetch again from server the isFavorite data is resseting to the default false.

I save the data like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class JSONViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var listings: [ListingModel] = []
    // saving Json to Core Data...
    
    func saveData(contex: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        
        listings.forEach { (data) in
            
            let entity = Listing(context: contex)
            
            entity.id = Int64(data.id)
            entity.title = data.title
            entity.name = data.name
            entity.latitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.latitude))
            entity.longitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.longitude))
            entity.isFavorite = false // everytime i fetch again all the post get default value as isFavorite = false,
```

witch is overighting tha acual post's witch have already isFavorite = true

```
        }

        do{
           // saving all pending data at once
           try contex.save()

            print("success")
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
       
    }
    
    
    func fetchData(context: NSManagedObjectContext){
        
        let url = "https://... on line json"
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.addValue("swiftui2.0", forHTTPHeaderField: "field")
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, res, _) in
            
            guard let jsonData = data else{return}
            
            // check for errors
            
            let response = res as! HTTPURLResponse
            // checking by status code
            
            if response.statusCode == 404 {
                print("error Api Errror")
            }
            
            // fetching JSON Data ..
            do {
                let listings = try JSONDecoder().decode([ListingModel].self, from: jsonData)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  
                    self.listings = listings
                    self.saveData(contex: context)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        .resume()
    }
}
```

How can i check if data exist and only change what is new?

i have also set Constraints by "id".
and updated the PersistentContainer like this::

```swift
 let container: NSPersistentContainer
   
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "WebyCoreData")
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")       }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
    }
```

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Have tried also:

```swift
if entity.isFavorite == true {
                entity.isFavorite = true}
            else {
                entity.isFavorite = false}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is called an "upsert" (update / insert) - with that in mind you'll be able to find more help, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763277/most-efficient-way-to-insert-update-records-with-core-data for example

Comment: i have tried to create:  func updateData(context: NSManagedObjectContext){ .. } with no result. I have no idea how to check!.  (i am a beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your saveData function, try something like this:

```
 let listingFetch: NSFetchRequest<Listing> = Listing.fetchRequest()
  listingFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", Int64(data.id))

    do {
     let results:[Listing] = try contex.fetch(listingFetch)
        if results.count == 0 {

           let entity = Listing(context: contex)
           entity.id = Int64(data.id)
           entity.title = data.title
           entity.name = data.name
           entity.latitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.latitude))
           entity.longitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.longitude))
           entity.isFavorite = false

            try? contex.save()
           print ("Inserted Listing")
        }
        else
        {
           let entity = results[0]
           entity.title = data.title
           entity.name = data.name
           entity.latitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.latitude))
           entity.longitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.longitude))
           entity.isFavorite = true

            try? contex.save()
            print ("Updated Listing")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error inserting / updating Listing \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Update with Marius's full list of properties.
Also modified typo

```swift
    func saveData(contex: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        
       
        listings.forEach() { (data) in
            
        let listingFetch: NSFetchRequest<Listing> = Listing.fetchRequest()
          listingFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", data.id)
        
       
            do {
             let results:[Listing] = try contex.fetch(listingFetch)
                if results.count == 0 {

                   let entity = Listing(context: contex)
                    entity.id = Int64(data.id)
                    entity.title = data.title
                    entity.name = data.name
                    entity.category = data.category
                    entity.image = data.image
                    entity.publishdate = data.publishdate
                    entity.tagline = data.tagline
                    entity.content = data.content
                    entity.coverimage = data.coverimage
                    entity.galleryunu = data.galleryunu
                    entity.gallerydoi = data.gallerydoi
                    entity.gallerytrei = data.gallerytrei
                    entity.saleprice = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.saleprice))
                    entity.rentprice = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.rentprice))
                    entity.phone = data.phone
                    entity.email = data.email
                    entity.area = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.area))
                    entity.rooms = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.rooms))
                    entity.beds = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.beds))
                    entity.bathrooms = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.bathrooms))
                    entity.expires = data.expires
                    entity.adresa = data.adresa
                    entity.listingtype = data.listingtype
                    entity.latitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.latitude))
                    entity.longitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.longitude))
                   entity.isFavorite = false

                    try? contex.save()
                   print ("Inserted Listing")
                }
                else
                {
                   let entity = results[0]
                    entity.id = Int64(data.id)
                    entity.title = data.title
                    entity.name = data.name
                    entity.category = data.category
                    entity.image = data.image
                    entity.publishdate = data.publishdate
                    entity.tagline = data.tagline
                    entity.content = data.content
                    entity.coverimage = data.coverimage
                    entity.galleryunu = data.galleryunu
                    entity.gallerydoi = data.gallerydoi
                    entity.gallerytrei = data.gallerytrei
                    entity.saleprice = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.saleprice))
                    entity.rentprice = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.rentprice))
                    entity.phone = data.phone
                    entity.email = data.email
                    entity.area = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.area))
                    entity.rooms = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.rooms))
                    entity.beds = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.beds))
                    entity.bathrooms = Int64(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.bathrooms))
                    entity.expires = data.expires
                    entity.adresa = data.adresa
                    entity.listingtype = data.listingtype
                    entity.latitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.latitude))
                    entity.longitude = Double(truncating: NSNumber(value: data.longitude))
                   entity.isFavorite = true

                    try? contex.save()
                    print ("Updated Listing")
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("error inserting / updating Listing \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry, typo. can you change listingFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", data.id) to listingFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", Int64(data.id))

Comment: NSPredicate(format: "id = %@",  "\(Int64(data.id))") - solve the error but... Now all the posts get favorite. I have 7 posts on the server, when i refresh the data, all 7 gets favorited

Comment: I thought I saw in your other question that you were deleting listings which aren’t marked as favourite from core data before you re- fetch your data from server. Is that correct or are you no longer deleting from core data before the fetch?

Comment: Yes, i realise that only deleting the non favorite listing - will not update some info in the favorite listing witch stay un-updated in core data(if the price change  or listing was deleted from server). Now the refresh button i use only call fetch and save to core data.  jsonModel.fetchData(context: context)

Comment: Ah! Yes in that case my code will favourite them all. As you’ve found out :)

Comment: Ok. Two options then. 1) delete the non favourites first or 2) if you add an extra predicate into my code for isFavourite = true.

Comment: option 2. i want to update all data when i fetch again and keep the data of favorite listings in the same time

Comment: Ok. Just thinking this through - does it work if you just remove the line entity.isFavorite = true

Comment: Excellent - ok next problem is going to be that if a listing gets deleted from your server then it won’t get deleted from your app. I’ve never done any work with server based data so I’m not sure how this is usually handled but I was thinking that as you are parsing through your server data then you could append the ids into an array. Then once you’ve finished updating and inserting then you do a fetch request for all items in your core data which have IDs which are not contained in the array and then delete them.

Comment: Sounds great! Could you give me a starting code? This logic should be created inside:  func saveData(contex: NSManagedObjectContext)?

Comment: I’d create new function in your viewModel which runs after saveData. You shouldn’t actually need to put the ids into a new array as you still have listings array. To be honest, you should now be starting to have code you can adapt for this. Take a copy of the fetch request we used in save data and amend the predicate to be a “NOT IN” predicate (give that a google for the syntax.) I think it will be something like “NOT (Id IN %@)”, listings.id   Debug that until it works. Then move on to delete the results you get